# Unique values of several columns (basic question)

Tags: r

When  I want to find the unique values of a column of a data set I write:

```
unique(data$column_01)
```

Now, I want to find the unique values of several columns of that data frame. I write:

```
unique((select(data, starts_with("column"))))
```

Can someone please clarify the mistake I am making here? What is the right formula to use and why this one is wrong?

Comment: lapply(mtcars[,c("carb", "gear")], function(x) unique(x)). mtcars data with carb and gear columns selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to "apply" or "map" the unique function to each column,

```
lapply(select(data, starts_with("column")), unique)
```

You can use `sapply` or `purrr::map` instead of `lapply` for slight variations in behavior. [This FAQ gives an excellent overview of the base options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7141669/903061) and when they are applicable. See the `purrr` package documentation for information about that.

As for "why this one is wrong" - `unique()` applied to a data frame will give you the unique rows of the data frame. This is different than the unique values of each column. Generally, functions may need to work differently on data frames than on vectors (columns), so `foo(dataframe)` cannot be assumed to be `foo()` applied to each column. So we use `lapply` or similar functions to specifically apply `foo()` to each column.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
    summarise(across(starts_with('column'), ~ list(unique(.))))
```